# Can I see results of my flags

Tags: support, flagging

As I understand it, every time I flag a question for moderator attention, there is at least a chance that someone will look at it. Is there any way of seeing if the moderator agreed with my flag or not?

I want to know because I do not want to keep doing something that mods do not like, so I hope there is a way to see the feedback...

**Edit:**

I found my flag history by going to my personal page and clicking the number next to "Helpful flags". Is this the only way to get to the flag history?

Comment: There is more than just a chance - every flag gets read by at least one moderator, since otherwise they wouldn't go away and we'd have a huge stack of old flags to wade through.

Comment: With regard to your edit: it's the only way I know, but then again I rarely look at my flag history these days :)

Comment: @AlexBecker Oh. That is very very tricky to find. I would imagine it would fit next to the "questions", "answers", "tabs" and other such tabs...

Comment: You can take such a request to the devs by posting on meta.SO, but since I haven't heard many complaints about it I doubt they would go through the work of changing the interface.

Comment: I agree. I will get used to it, no problem, I just wanted to be sure.

Comment: @AlexBecker You wrote: *every flag gets read by at least one moderator*. Aren't some flags [handled by 10k+ users](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)?

Comment: @MartinSleziak That's a good point. Most flags aren't visible to non-mods in my experience, but some are. In *some* cases we still have to review whatever the 10k+ users did (although it takes effect without our intervention), but I'm not sure if that's *all* cases. Worth looking into.

Comment: @Alex: Have you done much flagging since being elected? (Or have you tried saying that you haven't?)

Comment: @MartinSleziak The 10K flag queue has been largely superseded by review queues, and there is even a [call to eliminate it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226092/251274) (note the author). Yes, many flags never reach moderators (close flags in particular), but this is not because of 10K queue. On the other hand, if the OP really means "moderator attention" = free-form flag, then those are shown to moderators only.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Moderators can actually leave each other notes by adding flags to questions in a certain way that only other mods can see.  Often when a flag is tough to resolve (controversial or requiring a lot of investigation) this is how we communicate about it until a consensus is reached.  Other than that, we don't flag much, since our flags are binding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in comments, flag history is accessible through the helpful flag counter on the profile page. The number is shown in blue to suggest it's clickable:

[image: stats]

(Interestingly, the *recent names* number is also clickable, despite not being blue. Would clicking "profile views" show the list of my potential customers? Aww... no).

The idea of adding a tab for flags was [brought up before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174938/251274), and wasn't met with enough enthusiasm for it to materialize. I agree with the principal objection: shoving declined flags in user's face is more likely to be distracting than helpful. More angry meta threads "Would moderator explain his act?", etc.

[image: From the profile of Won't on meta.SO]

Comment: Is eating worms the cheap and effective way to diet?